# How to add wordpress specific post format

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to add worddpress specific post format?
The format I want to add is -> doctor

http://354.today/wpscreen.jpg

I try this code and this code not working

```
add_action('init', 'my_theme_slug_add_post_formats_to_page', 11); function my_theme_slug_add_post_formats_to_page(){
add_post_type_support( 'doctor', 'post-formats' );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_format', 'doctor' );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add post formats to your custom post type of 'doctor', but you cannot create your own custom post format called 'doctor'.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats